# JVM crashed with regards to memory allocation / Stack Guard pages deallocation

Tags: java, unix, jvm

We recently faced a JVM crash with regards to a java application.

Crash logs:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to protect stack guard pages failed.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f7d74f56000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f7d7131a000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

JDK used: `1.7.0_71-64`
OS details: `2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 26 13:37:13 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

On searching about the same 2 possibilities were found:

1. Swap space consumed on Unix box itself. -> Checked was not an issue as memory was available in plenty on the box.
2. pmap limit reached -> We don't have stats at what was the state around the time when process crashed.

Also there is a observation that the process had consumed a lot of memory under `VIRT` virtual memory. Does this tie up with anything?

Would be great if anyone can share any past experience around this error. Or has seen anything like it.

Comment: Do you have hs_error file generated ?

Comment: Even though the 2.6 kernel is very old, Java 7 supports older versions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @SMA hs_error file is not present on the box.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : Just to provide more context, the application was running fine. Its just we encountered the crash now. And post restart it's working fine. So looks like some problem happened and caused the crash.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj it looks like some resource had run out, though I couldn't say what if you have plenty of swap space free.

Comment: Yes this one's tricky. As we are not sure, what was the root cause. But do you have an idea around VIRT memory (it was around 50 gigs), but that's reclaimable right?

Comment: With every jvm crash, you should get hs_error file which would explain due  to which resource your jvm crashed. Check your home directory or from where you start your application

Comment: @SMA , as of now it's not present. As a corrective step, I am adding the -XX:ErrorFile argument to ensure we have one next time.